Why C++20 compound requirement doesn't apply the same rule as decltype when the expression is just an id?
I am a C++17 user, and I am now trying to get familiar with concepts, which were introduced in C++20.
I wrote a function with a requirement such like:
template <auto V>
void foo()
  requires requires(decltype(V) v) {
    { v } -> std::same_as<int>;
  }
{}

I found this foo() cannot accept the integer argument as I thought. I changed decltype(V) to int, but it still didn't work.
I tried to find something useful in the error message, and I found that the compiler deduced the return type of v as a reference int&. I replaced int v with int&& v, and the compiler still got int&.
This phenomenon reminded me of the rules of decltype. At first, I believed that expression in a compound requirement will be applied to the same rules as decltype. However, in decltype(expr), if expr is just an id, then the result type is exactly the same type as the type of expr. Only when the expr is a non-id expression does decltype(expr) result in a non-reference, lvalue reference, or rvalue reference when the expr is prvalue, lvalue, or xvalue, respectively.
After such examination, the conclusion I boiled down is that in the compound requirement, I should treat {expr} as {(expr)}, and then it will make sense for me.
So, why are the rules in a compound requirement different?

https://godbolt.org/z/71YEqG11d

@MarekR I didn't get it. In your case all the compilation without defining ALT are failed. And you have { v } -> std::same_as<int>; when #ifnef ALT

This just proves that { v } is evaluated to different type then you are expecting. It also provides MCVE - if it doesn't matches thing you have on your mind, please provide your own.

Why does decltype have a special casing for certain kinds of expressions in the first place? I think it is there only because otherwise it would be impossible to obtain the actual declared type of an entity. But for requires that doesn't matter. It intents to verify the validity, type and value category of certain expressions. It would be a hindrance if it sometimes didn't actually verify the type and value category of the expression itself. You don't need to use a requires expression to constrain the type of v. That can be done with std::same_as<decltype(v), int> instead.

Also, just to be clear, if that is your question, the compound requirement tests the expression as if the type is calculated from decltype((expr)), not decltype(expr), so that the special cases are skipped.

decltype((expression)) must satisfy the constraint imposed by the type-constraint.
